# Find dates with intervals

Tags: sql

I have a table full of orders where I want to find the email adresses of customers who have placed orders more than three months ago and that also have not ordered more recent than 3 months. For example

Don't include:

```
| testman@email.com| 2021-01-01|
| testman@email.com| 2021-05-01|
```

Do include

```
| testman2@email.com| 2021-01-01|
```

I'm not sure how to do this, my start is:

```
select distinct email 
from orders 
where order date > 2021-03-28
```

but don't know how to continue, thanks for any help!

Comment: Tag your RDBS: MySQL, Oracle, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you are trying to find e-mails that have not placed an order during the last three months..?

Let's assume we have a table..

[Table of Orders- Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csiIb.png)

Using the MAX-function we find the most recent order date for each e-mail. Then filter that result with the HAVING clause to find e-mails whose most recent orders are before 28.3.2021

```
SELECT E-mail, MAX([Order Date])
FROM Orders
GROUP BY E-mail
HAVING MAX([Order Date]) <= '2021-03-28'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed to do. I can't upvote you because my account level is too low but thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks, just did! I'm such a noob at this forum